# using union in a complex query

Tags: mysql, sql, sqlite

This is my sql code. when  I run it on mysql bench it runs just fine but there is a syntax error around the place where union is which does not affect the end result. I have tried to add brackets to separate the union parts but I still end up with the same syntax error.
Not that it seemingly seem to be working just fine when i run it.

```
SELECT date, time_code, number, power
FROM power_total
WHERE number IN ( 
                  SELECT number
                  FROM table_1 AS b
                  WHERE something
                    AND something
                    AND something
                    AND type = 1

                  UNION

                  SELECT dem.number AS number
                  FROM table_1 AS b
                  INNER JOIN (SELECT re.point_number AS number
                              FROM table_2 AS re
                              INNER JOIN table_3 AS dc
                                ON something = something
                              WHERE type_id IN (1 , 2)
                                 AND something IS NULL
                                 AND date <= '2016-09-01'
                            ) AS dem
                    ON dem.number = b.number
                 )
AND date BETWEEN '20160901' AND '20160930'
```

Comment: You have error in last line of your query remove last two brackets in last line. if you want to check then you can refer this url : http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/9eecb/20947

Comment: Add your  database schema for tables in your question.

Answer (score -1):

> Use fallowing query for desire output:

```
SELECT date, time_code, number, power FROM power_total
    WHERE number IN (  SELECT number  FROM table_1 AS b 
                                      WHERE something =something        
                                      AND something=something
                                      AND something=something
                                      AND type = 1
                      UNION
                      SELECT dem.number AS number   FROM table_1 AS b
                      INNER JOIN (SELECT re.point_number AS number    FROM table_2 AS re
                                  INNER JOIN table_3 AS dc 
                                    ON something = something
                                      WHERE type_id IN (1 , 2)
                                     AND something IS NULL
                                     AND date <= '2016-09-01'
                                ) AS dem
                        ON dem.number = b.number) 
             AND date BETWEEN '20160901' AND '20160930'
```